# Using zlib with java and ruby

Tags: java, ruby, zlib

I'm trying to decompress data in java but I'm stuck at some point. I deflate my data in ruby by using zlib gem and calling inflate function in java to decompress it and on my java console I only see tens of squares as decompressed data. I tried to decompress the data in ruby which worked perfectly. So is there any way that ruby zlib library to deflate data such that java's built in classes can inflate it?

**Compressing in ruby**

```
compressed_data = Zlib::Deflate.deflate(message)
```

**Decompressing in java**

```
public static String decompress(String s) { 

       Inflater inf = new Inflater();
       byte[] buffer = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
       int len = buffer.length;
       byte[] decomp = new byte[len];
       inf.setInput(buffer);
       try {
           inf.inflate(decomp, 0, len);
           inf.end();
       } catch (DataFormatException e) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
       }
       return new String(decomp, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   }
```

Comment: Your first, fundamental error is to use `String` to handle binary data!

Comment: Yeah, you are right, changed the parameter from string to byte and worked